# Python: how to determine if a list of sentence exist in a string

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a list ["one day", "second day"], how to determine if each List exists in a specified string?

string_to_be_searched = "one day i will find you"

It does return the actual sentence found

Comment: Coding something in python would be a good start. You can search SO on how to find stuff in strings - there are a couple hundred hits for that. If you have tried code that is broken, share it: [mre] - if not, read the link and also read through [ask] and [edit] your question into shape.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
lst = ["one day", "second day"]
string = """one day i will find you"""


for item in lst:
    if item in string:
        print(f"'{item}' IS PRESENT in the string '{string}'")
    else:
        print(f"'{item}' iS MISSING from the string '{string}'")
```

Prints

```
'one day' IS PRESENT in the string 'one day i will find you'
'second day' iS MISSING from the string 'one day i will find you'
```

Comment: `def find_the_word(lst, string):
    return set(lst).intersection(string.split())
for word in find_the_word(lst, string):
     print(word)`

How to archive using the intersection. right now it can only work with one word @GreyMurav

Comment: `def find_the_word(word_list, msgtext):
    return set(word_list).intersection(msgtext.split())

word_list = ["word1","word2 word3"]
msgtext = " word1 aslo have word2 word3"

for word in find_the_word(word_list, msgtext):
             print(word)`

right now it only matches if the list item has 1 word and is unable to match if the list item has 2 words.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: try to replace `word_list = ["word1", "word2 word3"]` with `word_list = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]`

Comment: But it's not the solution because if word1 is present in the 2nd item with an extra word then it will match in both cases @GreyMurav

Comment: It seems I do not quite understand the task. Could you edit your post by adding an example of `input data` and more importantly, the example of expected `output data` of the code?